# Is it possible to auto fill the Wordpress title field with today's date?

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

When I click "Add New" (and this would be for a custom post type named "day"), I'd like the Title field be pre-filled with the current date (preferably in Y-m-d format).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a filter that lets you set a default:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/default_title/

```
add_filter('default_title', function ($title) {
    global $post_type;
    if ('post' == $post_type) {
        return date('Y-m-d');
    }
    return $title;
});
```

Comment: Here is link if you want to edit date format. https://wordpress.org/support/article/formatting-date-and-time/